# scrolling in PerseiLayout with FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, scroll, fragment-tab-host

I'm using `PerseiLayout` from [Github](https://github.com/android-cjj/Persei.android) and it worked fine in all fragments except the fragment I'm using `FragmentTabHost` on it where the scroll down won't show the Persei menu : [image: this menu won't be showen with scrolling down]

This my code for the fragment which contains the `TabHostFragment` :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_tabhost_fragment, container, false);


    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    View indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    setTabIcon(indicator,R.mipmap.icon1,"Tab1");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator(indicator),
            Fragment1.class, null);
    indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    setTabIcon(indicator, R.mipmap.icon2, "Tab2");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator(indicator),
            Fragment2.class, null);
    indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    setTabIcon(indicator, R.mipmap.icon3, "Tab3");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator(indicator),
            Fragment3.class, null);
    return rootView;
}
```

the_tabhost_fragment.xml code :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Fragment1's layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first tab !"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit :**
I don't know if this can help but I realised that the scroll down works when I start scrolling from the TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very weird way to solve the problem but I'm not convinced with it, based on my edit, I tried to add a `ListView` on the layout, so my layout became like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first tab !"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And bang ! it worked !
Can anyone explain why it worked with a `ListView` ?
And I hope that anyone can give me more logical way to solve the problem !